# How can I retrieve the JSON token and login and should I use SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, authentication, token

I am new to android studio and this whole  API JSON protocols. I am trying to make a login service to work. It gets the info for a successful login from a backend server shown in the BASE_URL and a successful login returns a status and a token.So I have the following LoginActivity code :

```
package com.example.mydoctor

import android.accounts.AccountManager
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.mydoctor.api.ApiInterface
import com.example.mydoctor.models.LoginRequest
import com.example.mydoctor.models.LoginResponse
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*
import org.json.JSONObject
import retrofit2.*
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory


const val BASE_URL = "https://docappmy.herokuapp.com/mydoctor/user/"

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        val clickRegister = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.clickRegister)
        clickRegister.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, RegisterActivity::class.java);
            startActivity(intent)

        }

//        val loginbtm = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.loginbtm)
//        loginbtm.setOnClickListener {
//            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java);
//            startActivity(intent)
//
//        }

        val loginbutton = loginbtm
        var amka = ""
        var password = ""

        loginbutton.setOnClickListener {

            amka = amka_edit_text.text.toString().trim()
            password = password_edit_text.text.toString().trim()

            Log.d("values","The AMKA is: $amka, The password is: $password")



        val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build()
            .create(ApiInterface::class.java)

        val retrofitData = retrofitBuilder.loginUser(LoginRequest(amka,password))

        retrofitData.enqueue(object:Callback<LoginResponse>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginResponse>, response: Response<LoginResponse>) {
                val responseData = response.body()
                Log.d("SuccessLogin","The response is: $responseData")
//                val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
//                startActivity(intent)


            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity,"FailureLogin",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Log.d("loginerror","loginerror: ${t.localizedMessage} - ${t.stackTrace} - ${t.message}")
            }

        })


    }
```

this LoginRequest :

```
package com.example.mydoctor.models

data class LoginRequest(
    val amka: String, val password: String
)
```

this LoginResponse :

package com.example.mydoctor.models

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class LoginResponse(
    @SerializedName("status")
    val status: String,
    @SerializedName("Token")
    val token: String
)
```

And this ApiInterface :

```
package com.example.mydoctor.api

import com.example.mydoctor.models.LoginRequest
import com.example.mydoctor.models.LoginResponse
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.Body
import retrofit2.http.POST

interface ApiInterface {
    @POST("login")
    fun loginUser(
        @Body loginRequest: LoginRequest
    ): Call<LoginResponse>

}
```

So I want to retrieve the values of "status" and "token" and then make the login button take me to my main activity upon successful login (correct AMKA (an 11-digit number related to health insurance) and password. How can I retrieve them and have a proper login ? Should I use SharedPreferences and if so how ? I am really confused. Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I started adding the following function but then I need to enter where the token is stored and don't know how to express that :

```
   private fun saveData() {
        if(amka_edit_text.text.isEmpty()){
            amka_edit_text.error = "Please enter an AMKA"
            return
        }

        if(password_edit_text.text.isEmpty()){
            password_edit_text.error = "Please enter a password"
        }

        val mypref = getSharedPreferences("mypref", MODE_PRIVATE)

        val editor = mypref.edit()

        editor.putString("token",)
```

Comment: Hello, you can store the token in Shared Preferences. There should be another endpoint where you can verify with this token. You should never store information such as username and password in clear text. You can use Encrypted Shared Preferences for sensitive informations. (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences)

Comment: @serkancay Hello thank you. How can I store the Token in Shared Preferences ?

Comment: I posted an answer. I hope I was able to explain.

Comment: `Should I use SharedPreferences and if so how`, why would you want/need to use shared prefs, what does it achieve ? what exactly is sharedprefs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Shared Preferences.

**1. Write data to shared preferences**

The following code block saves the token value in shared preferences

Put the code below in your onResponse callback:

```
val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val editor = sharedPref.edit()
editor.putString("TOKEN", responseData.token)
editor.apply()
```

**2. Read data from shared preferences**

```
val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val token = sharedPref.getString("TOKEN", null)
```

You can take this token value where you need it.

Note: Shared preferences stores data in an XML file with key-value. In the example above, the "TOKEN" string value becomes your key. If a value cannot be found with this key, it will return null. In this way, you can check if there is a saved token.

If you want more details, you can review this document: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

I also suggest you look into Encrypted Shared Preferences, which is a safer way for storing sensitive data: https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data

Comment: Thank you for the analytical reply. i have to ask though, getString() at the read data part should be getting two parameters right ? One for key and one for default Value. If I only put one of them I get an error.

Comment: Yes, if there is no value for the key you provide, the default value will return. Sorry I missed it.